# Do session and entity manager refer to the same persistence context, or do they have their own implementation?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, persistence

I have a important question related to Session and EntityManager in hibernate. I know that through either the session object or entitymanager object you can talk to the persistence context. My question is that when you use either one, the session object or entity manager object, will the persistence context you are talking to be the same in both cases? For instance lets imagine(hypothetically) there is a concrete implementation called PersistenceContext then if I use either session or entitymanager, will they both be referring to an instance of PersistanceContext when I use methods like `session.get()`, or `entityManager.find()`, or do they both have their own implementation of PersistanceContext?

Edit:
I'm using version 4.3 and up and I am obtaining session and EntityManager via SessionFactory and EntityManagerFactory.

Comment: Please specify the version of Hibernate you're using and how you're obtaining the context.

Comment: I'm using version 4.3 and up and I am obtaining session and EntityManager via SessionFactory and EntityManagerFactory.

Comment: What is "4.3 and up"? The exact (minor) version matters; there were important changes regarding this in recent developments. (Generally, of course, you should just use JPA and not use Session at all--why are you trying to use both?)

Comment: My question is lets say you use EntityManager, now whenever you get or save an entity it goes through the persistence context, same as with session. What I am asking is whether the thing that we call the "persistence context" is different for both the EntityManager and Session API? like lets say there is a underlying abstraction called the persistenceContext, then regardless of whether I'm using session or entityManager will they both refer to that persistenceContext when creating the persistence context, or do they have their own implementation of persistenceContext.

Comment: It depends on the specific version. Why do you care instead of only using `EntityManager`?

Comment: I know you are supposed to only use either Session or EntityManager(EM), and your not supposed to use them interchangeably, i'm just confused with how the persistence context is created when using either session or EM. Does the session api have its on persistence context implementation that is different from EM's implementation of the persistence context? Or do they both use a standard JPA based implementation of the persistence Context?

Comment: I also want to know how common is it to use Session compared to EntityManager, and which one is more popular in the field?

Comment: Session is the outdated interface. JPA is the standardization (based largely on Hibernate, with some other contributions), and Hibernate now recommends using the JPA interface. It's not competing alternatives so much as "old" and "new".